# how do I set and get a property using mock objects in phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I created a mock object as follows:

```
        $mock_kyc = $this->getMockBuilder('Group_KYC_Model')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['api_record', '__get'])
            ->getMock();
```

I want to set the id of the mock_kyc object. How do I do that?

Can I just do $kyc->id = 12345;

Comment: Did you even try? Anyway see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558183/phpunit-mockbuilder-set-mock-object-internal-property

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do

`$mock_kyc->id = 12345;`

If id is private / protected, setter should help.